# Create new stored procedure using code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to be able to create a new stored procedure with code first using MVC5 EF6.

All resources I've found are for mapping existing stored procedures.

I have found [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/async-and-stored-procedures-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) that generates stored procedures for insert, update and delete.

The generated code seems to have syntax for creating stored procedures from code, but I am unsure of the proper approach for writing these on my own through code first.

To clarify on my question:

I am looking to create a new stored procedure through code, not generate stored procedures for CUD. I am not yet completely familiar with the entirety of the code first approach, so I am unsure of where I would experiment with the 'CreateStoredProcedure' function used in the linked article in order for it to generate the stored procedure on the PM 'Update-Database" command.

Comment: The link you posted has all the steps needed to accomplish this..

Comment: The link I posted appears to generate the stored procedures, which is the majority of what I want to do, but what I am asking for is more of what is the proper manual way to create a stored procedure using code first. I can probably throw something together that works, but doesn't mean it's the right way to do it.